# Tangent plane through two surfaces

Tags: calculus

Determine the constant A to get a tangent plane that goes through $x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 = A$ and $xy+z^2=2$ in the same point.

If i plot the graph i get that A should be 4, and the tangen plane is $z=\sqrt{2}$.

I having trouble with showing this with mathematics.

I've done:
$$f(x,y,z)=xy+z^2-2\\
f_{1}=y,\ f_{2}=x,\ f_{3}=2z\\
f_{plane}=y(x-a)+x(y-b)+2z(z-c)=0\\
g(x,y,z)=x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 - A\\
g_{1}=2x,\ g_{2}=2y,\ g_{3}=2z\\
g_{plane}=2x(x-a)+2y(y-b)+2z(z-c)=0\\
$$

Both planes got $2z(z-c)$. Can i do something with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plane is tangent to both at the same point, they are tangent to each other and do not intersect.

$x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 - A = 0$ ...(i)

$xy+z^2 - 2 = 0$ ..(ii)

Solving both equations to find the tangent point,

$x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 - A = 2(xy+z^2 - 2) \implies (x - y)^2 - A + 4 = 0$

To make sure there is only one solution to the equation $A-4 = 0$ i.e $A = 4$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Where did the first 2 in $2(xy+z2−2)$ came from?

Comment: That is just to take out $z$ to try and solve two equations to find the intersection / tangent point.